# Bing Search & Bing API: Country-specific queries

Tags: bing, bing-api

I'm new to Bing API. I read the docs and discussions yet still have a question. When restricting results to a specific country, what is the difference between `Request.Market="xx-YY"` (API), `loc:xx` (search query) and `?cc=xx` (url parameter)?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps: http://www.bing.com/community/developer/f/12245/t/649007.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that the result of using, say, `market=es-es` differs from that of combination `loc:es` and `language:es`. It puzzles me.